# Change Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart programmaticaly

Tags: magento-1.9, setup-script, installer

When I go to **System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options**, I can change Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart.

I need to do that in setup script. How to do that via setup script? I tried setStoreConfig but I probably used wrong node and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('cataloginventory/item_options/max_sale_qty', '10000', 'default', 0);
```